# TabControl in UserControl is not editable in Design Mode

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, user-controls

I am creating a simple Wizard control w/ TabControl and Couple of Buttons (Next, Back). Goal is give this user controls to developers so they can add their own steps, and controls in the stepes.

Everything works fine, EXCEPT the ability to select tabs that are added and drop controls in each tab item.

How do I enable tabcontrol to be editable in designer.

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]
public partial class WizardControl : UserControl
{
    private Button Button_Final;
    private TabControl TabControl1;
    private UltraTabSharedControlsPage ultraTabSharedControlsPage1;
    private EaseButton Button_Next;
    private EaseButton Button_Back;
    private SplitContainer splitContainer1;
    private WizardContainer wizardContainer1;

    public WizardControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Description("Final Button Text"), Category("Data")]
    public string FinalButtonText
    {
        get => Button_Final.Text;
        set => Button_Final.Text = value;
    }

    [Category("Wizard"), Description("Collection of wizard pages.")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public WizardPages Pages => wizardContainer1.Pages;

    [Category("Wizard"), Description("TabControl")]
    [Browsable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public TabControl TabControl => wizardContainer1.TabControl;        
    
}
```

}

Container:

```
[ToolboxItem(true), ToolboxBitmap(typeof(WizardControl))]
[Description("Provides a container for wizard pages.")]
[DefaultProperty("Pages"), DefaultEvent("SelectedPageChanged")]
public class WizardContainer : ContainerControl, ISupportInitialize
{
    private bool initializing;
    public WizardContainer()
    {
        Pages = new WizardPages(this);
        Pages.OnAdd += Pages_OnAdd;
    }

    private void Pages_OnAdd(object sender, NewTabEventArgs e)
    {
        UltraTab tab = new UltraTab();
        tab.Key = e.Id.ToString();
        tab.Text = e.Title;
        TabControl.Tabs.Add(tab);
    }

    public void BeginInit() => initializing = true;

    public void EndInit() => initializing = false;

    [Category("Wizard"), Description("Collection of wizard pages.")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public WizardPages Pages { get; }

    public Button NextButton
    {
        get
        {
            return (Button)this.Controls.Find("Button_Next", true).ElementAtOrDefault(0);
        }
    }

    public Button BackButton
    {
        get
        {
            return (Button)this.Controls.Find("Button_Back", true).ElementAtOrDefault(0);
        }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public TabControl TabControl
    {
        get
        {
            return (TabControl)this.Controls.Find("TabControl1", true).ElementAtOrDefault(0);
        }
    }

    public UltraTabSharedControlsPage UltraTabSharedControlsPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (UltraTabSharedControlsPage)this.Controls.Find("ultraTabSharedControlsPage1", true).ElementAtOrDefault(0);
        }
    }

    internal void MoveNext()
    {
        if (TabControl != null && TabControl.SelectedTab != null)
        {
            var index = TabControl.SelectedTab.Index;
            var newIndex = index + 1;
            if (newIndex != TabControl.Tabs.Count)
            {
                TabControl.SelectedTab = TabControl.Tabs[newIndex];
            }
            bool isPageValid = false;
            var page = Pages.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
            if(page != null)
            {
                isPageValid = page.IsValid;
            }

            NextButton.Enabled = newIndex == TabControl.Tabs.Count && isPageValid;
            BackButton.Enabled = newIndex != 0;
        }        
    }

    internal void MoveBack()
    {
        if (TabControl != null && TabControl.SelectedTab != null)
        {
            var index = TabControl.SelectedTab.Index;
            var newIndex = index - 1;
            if (newIndex != -1)
            {
                TabControl.SelectedTab = TabControl.Tabs[newIndex];
            }

            NextButton.Enabled = newIndex != TabControl.Tabs.Count;
            BackButton.Enabled = newIndex != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Derive a class from `ParentControlDesigner`, add `[Designer(typeof(MyParentDesigner))]` to both `WizardControl` and `WizardContainer`. In the `Initialize()` override of these custom Designers, add, e.g., `var wiz = ((WizardControl)this.Control).wizardContainer1;
this.EnableDesignMode(wiz, "wizardContainer1");`. The same goes for the TabControl of the `WizardContainer` class.

Comment: Note that I'm not sure how this `UltraTabSharedControlsPage` relates to the TabControl, if that's another Container of sort. You'll have to adapt this procedure to your design. Anyway, that's how you can enable DesignMode support for nested Containers.

Comment: Thanks that worked.. found an example of it: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37830/Designing-Nested-Controls